# Stored Procedure slowness after upgrade to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, upgrade, sql-server-2014

We have done a SQL Server upgrade from 2005 to 2014. Post upgrade one of the stored procedures is running very slow. It used to take about 10 mins which has now increased to 23 mins.

On further investigating, the execution time after fresh upgrade was perfectly fine and only after 3-4 executions it gets increased. I tried restoring the fresh database again and can confirm the above behaviour. Can someone help me out, since I have no clue what's happening!

I am a core DBA and not an application DBA so I don't have much knowledge about how stored procedures behave. Any help would be appreciated.

I am running using parameters :

```
exec [usp_RecalculateMV] '10', 8, 2015
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RecalculateMV]
       (@MarketID nvarchar(100), 
        @FromMonth int,
        @FromYear int)
AS
BEGIN
    --variable to hold any errors generated by the procedure
    DECLARE @ErrorCode INT
    DECLARE @MarketIDs INT
    DECLARE @Failed nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @SplitBy nvarchar(10)
    DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(11)

    -- 
    -- Changes done by Rupan
    -- Start (SER000008289) 
    DECLARE @cQtytoSplit FLOAT
    DECLARE @cOtherQty FLOAT
    DECLARE @cSplitThreshold INT
    DECLARE @cWeeklySplit NVARCHAR(35)
    DECLARE @cWeeklyBufferSplit NVARCHAR(35)
   DECLARE @SplitType VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @cSplitValue FLOAT 
DECLARE @jSplit INT
SET @jSplit = 1  
DECLARE @iSplit INT
SET @iSplit = 1 
DECLARE @cPackCode NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @cCustCode NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Week1Cursor INT
DECLARE @Week2Cursor INT
DECLARE @Week3Cursor INT
DECLARE @Week4Cursor INT
DECLARE @QtytoSplitCursor FLOAT
DECLARE @OtherQtyCursor FLOAT

DECLARE @itemp INT 
SET @itemp = 1

DECLARE @tempCount INT
DECLARE @tempPackCode      NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @tempCustomerCode  NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @tempWeeklyMV      VARCHAR(85)
DECLARE @tempWeeklBuffer   VARCHAR(85)
DECLARE @tempMVQTY         FLOAT
DECLARE @tempBufferQTY     FLOAT 


CREATE TABLE #tmp_IntialLoad ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                               MVQty           FLOAT,
                               BufferQty       FLOAT,
                               SplitThreshold  INT,
                               WeeklyMVQty     NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                               WeeklyBufferQty NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                               PackCode        NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                               CustomerCode    NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
                              );

CREATE TABLE  #tmp_SplitQTY ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                              SplitType    VARCHAR(15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
                              QtytoSplit   FLOAT,
                              OtherQty     FLOAT,
                              MarketID     NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                              Code         NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                              CustomerCode NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                              Week1        INT,
                              Week2        INT,                                
                              Week3        INT,
                              Week4        INT,                                                                    
                              Week1Buffer INT,
                              Week2Buffer INT,                                
                              Week3Buffer INT,
                              Week4Buffer INT
                            );   

 CREATE TABLE  #tmp_SplitBufferQTY ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                     SplitType  VARCHAR(15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, 
                                     QtytoSplit FLOAT,
                                     OtherQty   FLOAT,
                                     MarketID   NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     Code       NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     CustomerCode    NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     Week1      INT,
                                     Week2      INT,                                
                                     Week3      INT,
                                     Week4      INT                                         
                                    ); 
  CREATE TABLE  #tmp_FinalSplitQTY ( ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),                                      
                                     MarketID     NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     Code         NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     CustomerCode NVARCHAR(85) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
                                     Week1        INT,
                                     Week2        INT,                                
                                     Week3        INT,
                                     Week4        INT,                                                                    
                                     Week1Buffer INT,
                                     Week2Buffer INT,                                
                                     Week3Buffer INT,
                                     Week4Buffer INT,
                                     QtytoSplit FLOAT,
                                     OtherQty   FLOAT
                                   );  

-- END 


--table struc to hold the split string passed in above
DECLARE @T_TBL_Market TABLE
        (
           ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
           MarketID int --nvarchar(100)
         )
--populate the temporary table with the split market id's
INSERT INTO @T_TBL_Market
SELECT  * FROM dbo.Split(@MarketID, ',')

SET @StartDate = dbo.GetSafeDateFormat(1, @FromMonth, @FromYear)

--create a cursor to loop through the market id's
/* Start - Rupan 
DECLARE MarketCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT MarketID FROM @T_TBL_Market

--Open

OPEN MarketCursor
--loop through the markets
FETCH NEXT FROM MarketCursor
INTO @MarketIDs
******* End */

DECLARE @iMarketID INT
SET @iMarketID = 1 
DECLARE @iCount INT
SELECT @iCount = COUNT(*) FROM @T_TBL_Market  
/* Start - Rupan
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
 End */

  WHILE( @iMarketID <= @iCount )    
  BEGIN
     SELECT @MarketIDs = MarketID FROM @T_TBL_Market WHERE ID = @iMarketID    

     Print 'Inside While'  
    --Changes done by Parag on 08-04-2010, inserting values for customer detail
        --Deleting old values
        DELETE from TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE
        INSERT INTO TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE(CustomerSplitID,CustomerID, Week1Split, Week2Split, Week3Split, Week4Split, SplitThreshold, CustomerCode) 
        SELECT     dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.CustomerSplitID, dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerID, ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.Week1Split, 25) AS Week1Split, 
          ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.Week2Split, 25) AS Week2Split, ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.Week3Split, 25) AS Week3Split, 
          ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.Week4Split, 25) AS Week4Split, dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.SplitThreshold, 
          ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdSoldTo, '') + ISNULL(dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo, '') AS CustomerCode
        FROM         dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER LEFT OUTER JOIN
          dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT ON dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerID = dbo.TBL_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.CustomerID
        WHERE         TBL_CUSTOMER.marketid =@MarketIDs
    --Changes end

    --start a transaction to roll back if things go awry        
    BEGIN TRAN

    --delete the data for this market including and after the startdate

    Print'Before Delete' 
    DELETE FROM TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
    WHERE MarketID = @MarketIDs
      AND [Month] >= @StartDate
    Print'After Delete'  

    --check for errors
    SELECT @ErrorCode = @@Error
    --if no errors continue
    IF @ErrorCode = 0
    BEGIN
        Print'Inserting into CalculatedMV table'
        --do the basic recalculation of the MV and Buffer
        INSERT INTO TBL_CALCULATED_MV(
                                       MarketName, GroupDescription, MCCode, 
                                       ChannelDesc, PackCode, PackDesc, [Month], 
                                       MVQty,BufferQty,BufferPercentage,
                                       LocalCustomerCode,LocalCustomerName,
                                       CustomerCdSoldTo, CustomerCdShipTo, 
                                       BrandName, BrandCode, 
                                       MinMV, MarketID, 
                                       IntlCode, EPVOrgCode, AVOrgCode, LDDQty
                                     )
        SELECT DISTINCT  TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.MarketName, TBL_GROUP.GroupDescription, TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.MCCode, 
                         TBL_CHANNEL.ChannelDesc, VW_BASE_MV.PackCode, TBL_MARKET_PACK.PackDesc, VW_BASE_MV.[Month], 
                         VW_BASE_MV.RoundedBaseMV AS MVQty, 
                         dbo.CalculateBuffer(VW_BASE_MV.RoundedBaseMV, VW_LATEST_BUFFER.MonthValue, VW_LATEST_MINMV.MonthValue) AS BufferQty, 
                         VW_LATEST_BUFFER.MonthValue AS BufferPercentage,
                         CASE WHEN TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo IS NULL THEN
                              TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdSoldTo
                         ELSE
                              TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo
                         END AS LocalCustomerCode,
                         TBL_CUSTOMER.CustDescription, TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdSoldTo, TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo,
                         TBL_BRAND.BrandName, TBL_BRAND.BrandCode, 
                         VW_LATEST_MINMV.MonthValue, VW_BASE_MV.MarketID, 
                         TBL_MARKET_PACK.IntlCode, TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.EPVOrgCode, TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.AVOrgCode,
                         VW_BASE_MV.LDD
        FROM       TBL_CHANNEL 
        INNER JOIN VW_BASE_MV 
               ON TBL_CHANNEL.ChannelID = VW_BASE_MV.ChannelID 
        INNER JOIN TBL_MARKET_COMPANY 
               ON TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.MarketID = VW_BASE_MV.MarketID 
        INNER JOIN TBL_GROUP 
               ON TBL_GROUP.GroupID = TBL_MARKET_COMPANY.GroupID 
        INNER JOIN TBL_MARKET_PACK 
               ON VW_BASE_MV.MarketID = TBL_MARKET_PACK.MarketID    
              AND VW_BASE_MV.PackCode = TBL_MARKET_PACK.PackCode 
        INNER JOIN TBL_BRAND 
               ON TBL_BRAND.BrandID = TBL_MARKET_PACK.BrandID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CUSTOMER 
               ON VW_BASE_MV.CustomerID = TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_LATEST_BUFFER 
           ON VW_BASE_MV.MarketID = VW_LATEST_BUFFER.MarketID 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.PackCode = VW_LATEST_BUFFER.PackCode 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.ChannelID = VW_LATEST_BUFFER.ChannelID 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.[Month] = VW_LATEST_BUFFER.[Month] 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_LATEST_MINMV 
           ON VW_BASE_MV.MarketID = VW_LATEST_MINMV.MarketID 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.PackCode = VW_LATEST_MINMV.PackCode 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.ChannelID = VW_LATEST_MINMV.ChannelID 
          AND VW_BASE_MV.[Month] = VW_LATEST_MINMV.[Month]
        WHERE VW_BASE_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate
        AND VW_BASE_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
        AND VW_BASE_MV.RoundedBaseMV > 0
        AND CASE WHEN TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo IS NULL THEN
               TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdSoldTo
            ELSE
               TBL_CUSTOMER.CustomerCdShipTo
            END IS NOT NULL         --prevents customer still in the market share table
                            --but not in the customer table from being passed through
                            --to the calculated mv table

        --check for errors
        SELECT @ErrorCode = @@Error

     Print 'After Inserting into CalculatedMV table' 
     END

    IF @ErrorCode = 0 -- Start End of Errorcode 1
    BEGIN
        --find out if this market splits by Pack or by customer
        SELECT @SplitBy = ISNULL(SplitBy, 'Unassigned')
        FROM TBL_MARKET_COMPANY
        WHERE MarketID = @MarketIDs 

        --calculate the split MV and default the SumWeeklyMV and SumWeeklyBuffer
        --fields to the MV and Buffer quantities

             IF ISNULL(@SplitBy, 'Unassigned') = 'Unassigned'
             BEGIN
                UPDATE TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                SET 
                    Week1MV = 0, 
                    Week2MV = 0,
                    Week3MV = 0,
                    Week4MV = 0,
                    Week1Buffer = 0,
                    Week2Buffer = 0,
                    Week3Buffer = 0,
                    Week4Buffer = 0,
                    SumWeeklyMV = MVQty, 
                    SumWeeklyBuffer = BufferQty,
                    Split = 0
                WHERE 
                    TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                AND 
                    TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate

            END

            IF @SplitBy = 'Pack' -- Start of Pack              
            BEGIN 
                    Print 'Entering Pack sum update'
                    UPDATE TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                    SET 
                        SumWeeklyMV = MVQty, 
                        SumWeeklyBuffer = BufferQty,
                        Split = CASE WHEN MP.SplitThreshold IS NULL THEN
                                  0
                                WHEN MVQty + BufferQty < MP.SplitThreshold THEN
                                  0
                                ELSE
                                  1 
                                END
                      FROM TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                           VW_PACK_SPLIT
                       ON 
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = VW_PACK_SPLIT.PackCode
                      AND 
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = VW_PACK_SPLIT.MarketID
                      INNER JOIN 
                           TBL_MARKET_PACK MP
                      ON 
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = MP.MarketID 
                      AND 
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = MP.PackCode
                      WHERE
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                      AND 
                           TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate
                      Print 'After sum update'


                       Print'Before inserting into Initialload table'  
                       /* Changes Done By Rupan (SER00008289)*/
                       INSERT INTO #tmp_IntialLoad
                       SELECT DISTINCT 
                              MVQty,
                              BufferQty,
                              MP.SplitThreshold,
                              CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Split),
                              CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Split),
                              MP.PackCode,
                              TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode 
                       FROM
                              TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_PACK_SPLIT
                           ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = VW_PACK_SPLIT.PackCode
                          AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = VW_PACK_SPLIT.MarketID
                        INNER JOIN TBL_MARKET_PACK MP
                           ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = MP.MarketID 
                          AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = MP.PackCode
                        WHERE TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                        AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate
                        AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.Split=1   

                        SET @jSplit = 1 

                        Print 'After Initial load and before looping Initial Load'                   

                        WHILE(@jSplit <= (SELECT Count(*) FROM #tmp_IntialLoad ))
                        BEGIN                      
                            SELECT @cQtytoSplit        = MVQty,
                                   @cOtherQty          = BufferQty,
                                   @cSplitThreshold    = SplitThreshold,
                                   @cWeeklySplit       = WeeklyMVQty,
                                   @cWeeklyBufferSplit = WeeklyBufferQty,
                                   @cPackCode          = PackCode,
                                   @cCustCode          = CustomerCode 
                            FROM
                                   #tmp_IntialLoad
                            WHERE 
                                   ID = @jSplit                         


                            INSERT INTO #tmp_SplitQTY(SplitType,QtytoSplit,OtherQty,MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4)
                            EXEC CalculateSplitMV_working_SER8289 @cQtytoSplit,@cOtherQty,@cSplitThreshold,@cWeeklySplit,'MV',@MarketIDs,@cPackCode,NULL

                            INSERT INTO #tmp_SplitBufferQTY(SplitType,QtytoSplit,OtherQty,MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4)
                            EXEC CalculateSplitMV_working_SER8289 @cOtherQty,@cQtytoSplit,@cSplitThreshold,@cWeeklyBufferSplit,'BUFFER',@MarketIDs,@cPackCode,NULL 

                          SET @jSplit = @jSplit + 1     

                         END   

                         Print 'After looping Initial Load and before updating #tmp_SplitQTY' 

                         UPDATE ts
                         SET 
                              ts.Week1Buffer = tsb.Week1,
                              ts.Week2Buffer = tsb.Week2,
                              ts.Week3Buffer = tsb.Week3,
                              ts.Week4Buffer = tsb.Week4      
                         FROM
                              #tmp_SplitQTY ts,#tmp_SplitBufferQTY tsb
                         WHERE 
                              ts.ID = tsb.ID
                         AND
                              ts.MarketID = tsb.MarketID
                         AND
                              ts.Code = tsb.Code                              

                         SELECT @tempCount = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp_SplitQTY

                         Print 'After updating #tmp_SplitQTY and before calling usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize sp '  


                         WHILE(@itemp <= @tempCount)
                         BEGIN
                             SELECT  @tempPackCode     = Code,
                                     @tempCustomerCode = CustomerCode,
                                     @tempWeeklyMV     = CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4),
                                     @tempWeeklBuffer  = CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Buffer),
                                     @tempMVQTY        = QtytoSplit,
                                     @tempBufferQTY    = OtherQty 
                             FROM
                                     #tmp_SplitQTY 
                             WHERE
                                     ID = @itemp       



                             INSERT INTO #tmp_FinalSplitQTY(MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4,Week1Buffer,Week2Buffer,Week3Buffer,Week4Buffer,QtytoSplit,OtherQty) 
                             EXEC usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize @tempWeeklyMV,@tempWeeklBuffer,@MarketIDs,@tempPackCode,NULL,@tempMVQTY,@tempBufferQTY     
                             -- EXEC usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize '1,0,0,0','1,1,1,0',5,1120200,NULL,1,3

                            SET @itemp = @itemp + 1             
                         END

                         PRINT 'after usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize and before Entering MV/Buffer Update' 
                        /* Updating MV Quantity Weekly Split value */
                         UPDATE tc 
                            SET
                               tc.Week1MV = tfs.Week1,
                               tc.Week2MV = tfs.Week2,
                               tc.Week3MV = tfs.Week3,
                               tc.Week4MV = tfs.Week4,
                               tc.Week1Buffer = tfs.Week1Buffer,
                               tc.Week2Buffer = tfs.Week2Buffer,
                               tc.Week3Buffer = tfs.Week3Buffer,
                               tc.Week4Buffer = tfs.Week4Buffer 

                            FROM 
                                TBL_CALCULATED_MV tc,#tmp_FinalSplitQTY tfs
                            WHERE
                               tc.PackCode = tfs.code
                            AND 
                               tc.MarketID = tfs.MarketID                               
                            AND 
                                tc.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                            AND
                                tc.MVQty = tfs.QtytoSplit
                            AND
                                tc.BufferQty = tfs.OtherQty
                            AND
                                tc.[Month]>= @StartDate 
                            AND
                                tc.Split=1  
                     PRINT 'after MV/Buffer Update' 

                END -- End of Pack Condition

                IF @SplitBy = 'Customer' -- Start of Customer condition
                BEGIN
                     Print 'Entering Customer Sum update'
                        UPDATE TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                        SET                            
                           SumWeeklyMV = MVQty, 
                           SumWeeklyBuffer = BufferQty,
                           Split = CASE WHEN MP.SplitThreshold IS NULL THEN
                                       0
                                    WHEN MVQty + BufferQty < MP.SplitThreshold THEN
                                       0
                                    ELSE
                                       1 
                                   END
                            FROM TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
                            --LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_CUSTOMER_SPLIT
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE
                            ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode = TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE.CustomerCode
                            --ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode = VW_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.CustomerCode
                            INNER JOIN TBL_MARKET_PACK MP
                               ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = MP.MarketID 
                              AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = MP.PackCode
                            WHERE TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                            AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate   
                         --* Updating MV Quantity Weekly Split value */
                         /* Updating MV Quantity Weekly Split value */

                         Print 'After Customer Sum update'

                       Print'Before inserting into Initialload table' 
                       INSERT INTO #tmp_IntialLoad
                       SELECT DISTINCT 
                              MVQty,
                              BufferQty,
                              MP.SplitThreshold,
                             CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Split),
                             CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Split)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Split),
                              TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode,
                              TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode
                       FROM 
                              TBL_CALCULATED_MV
                           --LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_CUSTOMER_SPLIT
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE
                            ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode = TBL_CUSTOMER_CODE.CustomerCode
                            --ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.LocalCustomerCode = VW_CUSTOMER_SPLIT.CustomerCode
                            INNER JOIN TBL_MARKET_PACK MP
                               ON TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = MP.MarketID 
                              AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.PackCode = MP.PackCode
                            WHERE TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                            AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate 
                            AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.Split=1 

                        SET @jSplit = 1

                        Print 'After Initial load and before looping Initial Load'  
                        WHILE(@jSplit <= (SELECT Count(*) FROM #tmp_IntialLoad ))                           
                        BEGIN                      
                            SELECT @cQtytoSplit        = MVQty,
                                   @cOtherQty          = BufferQty,
                                   @cSplitThreshold    = SplitThreshold,
                                   @cWeeklySplit       = WeeklyMVQty,
                                   @cWeeklyBufferSplit = WeeklyBufferQty,
                                   @cPackCode          = PackCode,
                                   @cCustCode          = CustomerCode
                            FROM
                                   #tmp_IntialLoad
                            WHERE 
                                   ID = @jSplit                         

                            INSERT INTO #tmp_SplitQTY(SplitType,QtytoSplit,OtherQty,MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4)
                            EXEC CalculateSplitMV_working_SER8289 @cQtytoSplit,@cOtherQty,@cSplitThreshold,@cWeeklySplit,'MV',@MarketIDs,@cPackCode,@cCustCode

                            INSERT INTO #tmp_SplitBufferQTY(SplitType,QtytoSplit,OtherQty,MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4)
                            EXEC CalculateSplitMV_working_SER8289 @cOtherQty,@cQtytoSplit,@cSplitThreshold,@cWeeklyBufferSplit,'BUFFER',@MarketIDs,@cPackCode,@cCustCode 


                          SET @jSplit = @jSplit + 1  

                        END             

                          Print 'After looping Initial Load and before updating #tmp_SplitQTY'
                          UPDATE ts
                          SET 
                              ts.Week1Buffer = tsb.Week1,
                              ts.Week2Buffer = tsb.Week2,
                              ts.Week3Buffer = tsb.Week3,
                              ts.Week4Buffer = tsb.Week4      
                          FROM
                              #tmp_SplitQTY ts,#tmp_SplitBufferQTY tsb
                          WHERE 
                              ts.ID = tsb.ID
                          AND
                              ts.MarketID = tsb.MarketID
                          AND
                              ts.Code = tsb.Code 
                         AND
                              ts.CustomerCode = tsb.CustomerCode  


                         SELECT @tempCount = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp_SplitQTY

                         Print 'After updating #tmp_SplitQTY and before calling usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize sp ' 

                         WHILE(@itemp <= @tempCount)
                         BEGIN
                             SELECT  @tempPackCode     = Code,
                                     @tempCustomerCode = CustomerCode,
                                     @tempWeeklyMV     = CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4),
                                     @tempWeeklBuffer  = CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week1Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week2Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week3Buffer)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR,Week4Buffer),
                                     @tempMVQTY        = QtytoSplit,
                                     @tempBufferQTY    = OtherQty 
                             FROM
                                     #tmp_SplitQTY 
                             WHERE
                                     ID = @itemp       

                             INSERT INTO #tmp_FinalSplitQTY(MarketID,Code,CustomerCode,Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4,Week1Buffer,Week2Buffer,Week3Buffer,Week4Buffer,QtytoSplit,OtherQty) 
                             EXEC usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize @tempWeeklyMV,@tempWeeklBuffer,@MarketIDs,@tempPackCode,@tempCustomerCode,@tempMVQTY,@tempBufferQTY                              

                           SET @itemp = @itemp + 1
                         END 

                         PRINT 'after usp_Forecast_Calc_BoxSize and before Entering MV/Buffer Update' 
                        /* Updating MV Quantity Weekly Split value */
                         UPDATE tc 
                            SET
                               tc.Week1MV = tfs.Week1,
                               tc.Week2MV = tfs.Week2,
                               tc.Week3MV = tfs.Week3,
                               tc.Week4MV = tfs.Week4,
                               tc.Week1Buffer = tfs.Week1Buffer,
                               tc.Week2Buffer = tfs.Week2Buffer,
                               tc.Week3Buffer = tfs.Week3Buffer,
                               tc.Week4Buffer = tfs.Week4Buffer 

                            FROM 
                                TBL_CALCULATED_MV tc,#tmp_FinalSplitQTY tfs
                            WHERE
                               tc.PackCode = tfs.code
                            AND 
                               tc.MarketID = tfs.MarketID 
                            AND
                               tc.LocalCustomerCode = tfs.CustomerCode                              
                            AND 
                                tc.MarketID = @MarketIDs
                            AND
                                tc.MVQty = tfs.QtytoSplit
                            AND
                                tc.BufferQty = tfs.OtherQty
                            AND
                                tc.[Month]>= @StartDate 
                            AND
                                tc.Split=1                                                         
                        /* End */                                      
                     PRINT 'after MV/Buffer Update'       
                        --check for errors
                    SELECT @ErrorCode = @@Error
                END -- End of Customer condition

    END -- End of Errorcode 1
    IF @ErrorCode = 0
    BEGIN
        Print 'Inside sumweekly update' 
            --Update the SumWeeklyMV and SumWeeklyBuffer fields to be the sum of the 
            --splits for the rows that are to be split
            UPDATE TBL_CALCULATED_MV 
            SET 
                TBL_CALCULATED_MV.SumWeeklyMV = ISNULL(Week1MV,0) + ISNULL(Week2MV,0) + ISNULL(Week3MV,0) + ISNULL(Week4MV,0), 
                TBL_CALCULATED_MV.SumWeeklyBuffer = ISNULL(Week1Buffer,0) + ISNULL(Week2Buffer,0) + ISNULL(Week3Buffer,0) + ISNULL(Week4Buffer,0)
            WHERE TBL_CALCULATED_MV.Split=1
            and TBL_CALCULATED_MV.MarketID = @MarketIDs
            AND TBL_CALCULATED_MV.[Month] >= @StartDate

            --check for errors
            select @ErrorCode = @@Error
    END

    IF @ErrorCode = 0
     COMMIT TRAN        
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        set @Failed = @Failed + ',' + @MarketIDs
    END
    SET @ErrorCode = 0

        /* Start - Rupan 
        FETCH NEXT FROM MarketCursor
        INTO @MarketIDs
       End */

    DELETE FROM #tmp_IntialLoad
    DELETE FROM #tmp_SplitQTY 
    DELETE FROM #tmp_FinalSplitQTY     

 SET @iMarketID = @iMarketID + 1
 END   

/*CLOSE MarketCursor
DEALLOCATE MarketCursor
*/
  DROP TABLE #tmp_IntialLoad
  DROP TABLE #tmp_SplitQTY  
  DROP TABLE #tmp_FinalSplitQTY
--IF @Failed is null 
   --SELECT @SuccessFail = 'All markets were successfully re-calculated'
--ELSE
  -- SELECT @SuccessFail=@Failed               

END --  END of Procedure Begin
GO
```

Comment: http://thomaslarock.com/2014/06/upgrading-to-sql-server-2014-a-dozen-things-to-check/

Answer (score 0):

If it has not been done yet, you should:

- switch to compatibility lever 120
- rebuild indexes
- update statistics
- clear plan cache and force stored procedures recompile